# Canonical link to the same page

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, canonical-url

Recently I learned that e.g. Google was not indexing pages that didn't have canonical links, so in the code below, I am setting the canonical link to the homepage itself (index.html).

Question: for example, for the home page (index.html) is the canonical meta-tag below correct, or would it raise canonical-based meta tag page errors?

```html
<link rel="canonical" hreflang="en-us" href="http://www.company.com/index.html">
```

Below is a pic of the search console showing 32 pages that weren't indexed because of error "Duplicate page without cononical tag," and FYI there are no duplicate pages as they all have unique `filename.html`.

[image: pic]

Comment: *Would there be any potential issue with this?* Uh. Yeah! You are telling Google that your pages are a duplicate and hence Google is ignoring the page.

Comment: I removed your second question (a question post should always be about one topic). It could be its own question, but you’ll likely find several questions/answers on this site about it.

Comment: On which page (which URL) do you add this `link`?

Comment: I think you may be asking this: [Does a link rel canonical tag pointing back to the page itself cause an infinite loop that wastes crawl budget?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103892/does-a-link-rel-canonical-tag-pointing-back-to-the-page-itself-cause-an-infinite)   But if you made all your pages canonical to `index.html` that would be a problem.   Actually, why would you ever include `index.html` in the canonical?   Even for the home page that can be omitted for a much cleaner URL.

Comment: See also: [Multisites Network SEO::Can self-referencing canonical tag(rel=“canonical”) inside article improve google rating?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10834/multisites-network-seocan-self-referencing-canonical-tagrel-canonical-insi)

Comment: And where did you hear that Google doesn't index pages that don't have a canonical tag?   That is completely untrue.  Google indexes plenty of sites that don't use canonical tags at all.

Comment: Modified OP and reworded question specifically to elicit explicit information requested which I am not sure of.  Also added pic from search console proving that 32 .html files with unique filenames (i.e., all filenames are different) are not indexed because of lack of a cononical tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the canonical page to the page that you want to have indexed.

If your site has

> example.com/news/article/
>
> example.com/news/article
>
> example.com/news/article.html

all as the same page this is a duplicate content issue.

If you put a rel canonical tag of example.com/news/article pointing to your homepage then google won't index your news article page. You want your canonical tag to point to example.com/news/article